# Use Glue Catalog for Spark On EMR with Ranger plugin

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm trying to apply Apache Ranger integrated EMR.
So I installed Ranger Server (Admin Server) and EMR Plug-in for **EMR-FS** and **EMR-SPARK**.

**EMR-FS** works fine. However, it doesn't seem to work as intended in cases like **EMR-SPARK**.
When I have checked the “**Use for Spark table metadata**” option when I create my EMR cluster, all databases that I create on spark-sql and Already created from Glue should be visible here and all databases that I create here should be visible on Spark.

Currently, only "**Default**" is searched when querying Database with Spark-sql.

```sql
spark-sql> show databases;
default
Time taken: 2.364 seconds, Fetched 1 row(s)
```

When configuring EMR with Ranger plugin, "**Use the AWS Glue Data Catalog** to provide an external Hive metastore for Spark" is **this option also impossible?**

If this is not possible, **how can I search the Glue Catalog in Spark?**